# MPI_Allreduce is slow for 7 processes or more

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mpich

I've written this little `MPI_Allreduce` benchmark: [bench_mpi.cxx](https://github.com/dfroger/issue/blob/8b8bdd8e4b2b5e265c25fc2ba7077f6a108bb34a/mpi/bench_mpi.cxx).

It work well with `Open MPI 1.8.4` and `MPICH 1.4.1`.

The results (1 column for the number of processors, and 1 columns for the corresponding wall clock time) are [here](https://github.com/dfroger/issue/blob/8b8bdd8e4b2b5e265c25fc2ba7077f6a108bb34a/mpi/carla/conda-mpi4py-channel.openmpi.1.8.4.txt) or [here](https://github.com/dfroger/issue/blob/8b8bdd8e4b2b5e265c25fc2ba7077f6a108bb34a/mpi/carla/conda-default.mpich2.1.4.1p1.txt).

With `MPICH 3.1.4`, the wall clock time increase for 7, 8 or more processes: results are [here](https://github.com/dfroger/issue/blob/8b8bdd8e4b2b5e265c25fc2ba7077f6a108bb34a/mpi/carla/conda-mpi4py-channel.mpich.3.1.4.txt).

In a real code (edit: a Computational Fluid Dynamic software), but for all of the 3 above MPI implementation, I observe the same problem for 7, 8 or more processes, while I expect my code to be scallable to at least 8 or 16 processes.

So I'm trying to understand what could happen with the little benchmark and `MPICH 3.1.4`?

### edit

Here is a zoom in the figure Rob Latham give in his answer.

[image: idle]

What does the code do during the green rectangle? The `Mpi_Allreduce` operation starts too late.

### edit

I've posted another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039802/what-control-mpi-barrier-time-to-execute) on much more simpler code (just the time to execute `MPI_Barrier`).

Comment: You say "... for all of the 3 above MPI implementation, [you] observe the same problem..." but you also show benchmarking data that says you don't see this problem for OpenMPI 1.8.4 or MPICH 1.4.1; I don't understand.

Comment: **In my real code** and for all of the 3 above MPI implementation: My **real code** is a Computational Fluid Dynamic software. Sorry for the confusion, I will edit the question to make is clear.

Comment: How many physical cores are you running on? It looks to me like there may be only 4 actual cores which is why you get the same performance for 8 and (when the overhead of emulating more cores increases) worse performance for 16...

Comment: On the `otis` machine, I run on 8 processors of 4 cpu cores: https://github.com/dfroger/issue/blob/master/mpi/otis/cpuinfo. But the program only do usleep, no real computations, so does it matter?

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting you don't see this with OpenMPI or with earlier versions of MPICH, but the way your code is set up seems guaranteed to cause problems for any MPI collective.

You've given each process a variable amount of work to do.  The problem with that is the introduction of "pseudo-synchronization" -- the time other MPI processes spend waiting for the laggard to catch up and participate in the collective.

With point-to-point messaging the costs are clear, and probably follow [a LogP model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogP_machine)

Collective costs have an additional cost:  sometimes a process is blocked waiting for a participating process to send it some needed information.   In Allgather, well, all the processes have a data dependency on another.

When you have variable-sized work units, no process can make progress until the largest/slowest processor finishes.

If you instrument with MPE and display the trace in Jumpshot, it's easy to see this effect:
[image: Traced benchmark program]

I've added (see https://gist.github.com/roblatham00/b981fc875d3852c6b63f) red boxes for work, and the purple boxes are the default allgather color. The second iteration shows this most clearly: rank 0 spends almost no time in allgather .   Rank 2,3,4, and 5 have to wait for the slowpokes to catch up.
.

Comment: Thank. The maximum time MPI_Allreduce is blocked waiting for laggard with 8 procs is: basetime * overhead * niter / nproc = 0.2 * 1.05 * 1000 / 8 = 26.25, but I get the double.

Comment: Are you visualizing with jumpshot4?

Comment: i am!  it's been "community supported" for a few years now but I still have a soft spot for it.  I had to manually add calls around your usleep.   Editied answer to link to modified code.

Comment: So in your figure, I would expect MPI_Allreduce to run very fast, that is to have red block start immediately after the all previous red block have complete.

Comment: The semantics of allreduce preclude any process from exiting until all processes have entered, yes?  E.g., how can rank 7 collect data from a process that has not yet entered ALLREDUCE?  No red block (your usleep) can begin until allreduce is over.  You might find the non-blocking collectives in MPI-3 interesting, though!